# Joining two tables with different variables names

Tags: sql, sas

Still learning SAS/SQL and my friend gave me a task:

Description:
One table contains 20 variables and 1000 observations, another table contains 25 variables and 1500 observations. There's a primary key and all the observations from sheet 1 appear in sheet 2 under another variable name. Yet there's no two lines of records in both tables that contains full set of observations.

Task:
Match all the common variables.

It's not even programming problem for me but logical problem. May someone help me understand it? I've been thinking about it for days, trying solutions but I'm completely lost and I don't wanna leave it unsolved.

Comment: Look up Natural Join.

Comment: Unfortunately natural join needs the same variables names

Comment: I'm lost.  Can you give a little example of (10 records and 5 variables from each dataset, and the match you would want)?  If there is a primary key in both datasets for you to join, and the task is to identify which of the non-key variables match to each other (i.e. have the same values), Bruce Gilsen has a paper on identifying duplicate variables.  https://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2017/SESUG2017_Paper-74_Final_PDF.pdf

Comment: `Proc COMPARE` can compare data structures and data content.  When comparing content you would use `BY COMMON_KEY` and since one data set has the key under a different name, you would use a data set option to change that name to the common key `... compare=other_data(rename=other_key_name=common_key)`

Comment: Is this question simply, "What columns exist in table1 that also exist in table2?" - or am I missing something?  Perhaps you can provide sample tables, and desired result?  Simplify to just a few columns in each table for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. The problem is that two tables contain the same values but with different variable names. I've done it by a manual matching metod with a little help of joins nested in a loop. I'll provide the data soon for further consideration.